# HQL JoinTable not accessible

Tags: hibernate, hql, join

i have a many to many relationship between media and tags:

Medium:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@IndexColumn(name="tags_index_column")
@JoinTable(name="tag_map",
          joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="tag_id")},
          inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="item_id")})
private List<Tag> tags;
```

Tags:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="tags")
@JoinTable(name="tag_map",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="item_id")},
              inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="tag_id")})
private List<Medium> media;
```

I try to query the join table from hql but i always get an exception:

```
String resultQueryString = "From tag_map"

        Query resultQuery SessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(resultQueryString);
```

Exception:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: tag_map is not mapped [From tag_map]; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: tag_map is not mapped [From tag_map]
```

What i basically want to do is to query all media which has a tag with a specific id. Unfortunately i can't access the jointable.

Any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 9):

HQL queries are written in terms of entities, not tables, therefore you can't query an arbitrary table table.

So, you need to formulate a query in terms of logical relationships between entites rather than by accessing a join table directly, something like this:

```
select m from Medium m join m.tags t where t.id = ?
```

**See also:**

- [Chapter 16. HQL: The Hibernate Query Language](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html)